# How to stop the parser?

Tags: node.js, sax

I'm using node.js and SAX module to parse my XML documents.

I would like to block(abort) the parser when I find the node I was looking for.

I tried `parser.close()` but I get this error:

```
  if (this.error) throw this.error
                            ^
Error: Unexpected end
Line: 1
Column: 59
```

How can I block it without parsing the rest of the document that it is not useful to me?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the code for the SAX module, you can see why that error is thrown.

https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js/blob/master/lib/sax.js#L585

If you attempt to call parser.write() after an error is set, then it will throw an error. If you call parser.close() in the middle parsing, then it may set an error.

https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js/blob/master/lib/sax.js#L354

Don't don't call parser.write() after doing parser.close() and you should be set.